# CSS and JS files don't load on node.js server

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

This is my node.js file:

---

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/style.css')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  });

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
      });
  });

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
  });
```

---

I looked up multiple questions but they didn't seem to help.
I'm new to node.js and web programming as a whole.
And also my folder organization:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qf7Y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` instead. So that everything inside `/public` is accessible by your html page

Comment: Still doesn't work, it just gives me the raw html and no css or js. :/

Comment: How are you including your js/css file in the index.html?

Comment: CSS:   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/styles.css">
JS:    <script src='public/script.js'></script>

Comment: you don't need the `/public` prefix here anymore. Just write `style.css` and `script.js` in the href and src

Comment: Please accept the answer and upvote it if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your server.js file

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

and add css like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

Comment: ty for the help as well.